# Request all data from realm cache and keep data updated - iOS App Architecture

Tags: ios, swift, caching, architecture, realm

I'm updating data from multiple locations in my app. How can I keep data updated on all views?

I’m developing an app which contains a timeline, where you can see the posts from people who you are following. Also contains a user profile view, where you can see the posts created by itself, and every user can comment over a post (you can imagine an app inspired from instagram).
My app follows a VIP architecture, where all my scenes are built with a view, an interactor and a presenter. 
Also, I’m using Realm to cache my data.

So, my question is related with these posts and its data edition on cache:

Currently, in timeline I’m downloading all data and storing it in memory (a variable inside the timeline interactor). 
Now, imagine I go to user profile, I edit a post, for example, adding a location, and I return to the timeline. I don’t have the most recent data updated in timeline.

I need to keep the data updated all time. For this purpose, I thought the following scenario:

On timeline, the posts service downloads the posts and stores it on cache. Then, in memory, on timeline interactor, store only the id of the post and every time the table view needs to refresh its cells, ask to cache for the post with the corresponding id.

So, if I go to user profile and I edit a post, the post updates cache. Then, returning to timeline, when this post is displayed, I can get the cached data from the corresponding id.

That way would keep data updated. Would you implement this scenario? What’s the cost of ask to cache each time app needs to display the post?

[image: Resulting architecture scheme]